# Problema con ConnectionString en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema con una función que estoy haciendo. mi form1 tiene dos campos, un textbox y un combobox. con el Form1_Load carga con datos el combobox.Mis funciones de conexion son:

```
public static void AbrirConexion()
{
        conexion.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=*****; Initial Catalog=ZonaFranca; user id=*****;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        conexion.Open();
}

public static void CerrarConexion() { conexion.Close(); }
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es que en mi textbox al escribir un número, al dar enter me haga una consulta en la base de datos y me trajera una descripción, funciona bien, este es el código:

```
private void txt_documento_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
        //cargamos las listas
        AbrirConexion();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
        comando.Connection = conexion;
        string x = txt_documento.Text;

        comando.CommandText = "select Codigo,Descripcion from zf_TipoDoc where ltrim(rtrim(Codigo)) = '"+ x +"'";

        SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
                cmbbox_documento.Text = reader[1].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
        CerrarConexion();
        }
}
```

y por otro lado después creé esta función que me permitiera a mi seleccionar un elemento de este combobox y se cargara el dato en el textbox, el código:

```
private void txt_documento_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
        //cargamos las listas
        AbrirConexion();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
        comando.Connection = conexion;
        string x = txt_documento.Text;

        comando.CommandText = "select Codigo,Descripcion from zf_TipoDoc where ltrim(rtrim(Codigo)) = '"+ x +"'";

        SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
                cmbbox_documento.Text = reader[1].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
        CerrarConexion();
        }
}
```

El problema recae en que ahora si ingreso un dato en el textbox y presiono enter me sale un mensaje de error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No está autorizado a cambiar la propiedad 'ConnectionString'. El estado actual de la conexión es abierta.'

En mis dos funciones inicio y cierro la conexión pero igual me alega con que está abierta. Si ejecuto la función para seleccionar un item del combobox no me sale el error.

A Alguno de ustedes les ha pasado?

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Donde instancias el objeto `conexion`. ¿No debería venir como parámetro en el método `public static void AbrirConexion(SqlConnection conexion)`?. Y otra cosa, por que lo defines como `static`?

Comment: La conexiones a recursos como la base de datos o http a API/servicios son oro puro, y debes desconectar lo más rápido posible. Ya que como todo en esta vida es escaso (la cantidad de conexiones a una Db, los puertos etc) este límite lo debes saber. Por eso hay patrones que nos ayudan. Como te comenta Leandro más abajo, deberias ver patrón Repositorio para reforzar. O utilizar mecanismos de consultar y cortar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que nunca cierras las conexion, o en algun punto se esta quedando abierta.

Recomendaria no uses esa forma de proramar es para problemas, recomendaria que solo retornes el string del connectionstring y defines la conexion en un bloque `using`, asi sabras que el objeto se destruye correctamente luego de utilizarlo

```
public static string ObtenerConnectionString()
{
    return @"Data Source=*****; Initial Catalog=ZonaFranca; user id=*****;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
}



private void txt_documento_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        string connstring = ObtenerConnectionString();

        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string query = @"select Codigo,Descripcion from zf_TipoDoc 
                            where ltrim(rtrim(Codigo)) = @codigo";
            var comando = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            comando.Parameters.AdWithValue("@codigo", txt_documento.Text);

            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            cmbbox_documento.ValueMember = "Codigo";
            cmbbox_documento.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
            cmbbox_documento.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
```

Ademas

- usa siempre parametros, no se concatena en un string el valor
- si vas a cargar un combo usa el DataSource

Comment: Dejo una recomendación. Encapsula las llamadas a la Db en un componente separado (clase con patrón Repositorio por ejemplo) no importa si está dentro o en librería separada. Pero para generalizar las llamadas a la Db.

Comment: hola, buenos días. una consulta, en **var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);** qué vendría a ser **cmd** ? Dentro de la función no lo tienes definido